# Polymorphic recursion in OCaml: return values

Tags: recursion, ocaml, polymorphism

Continuing my series of questions regarding type-level arithmetic, I stumbled across another problem: return types of polymorphic recursive functions.

This is the code:

```
module Nat : sig
  type z = Z
  type 'n s = S of 'n

  type ('n) nat =
          Zero : (z) nat
        | Succ : ('n) nat -> ('n s) nat

  val of_int : int -> 'n nat
end = struct
  type z = Z
  type 'n s = S of 'n
  type ( 'n) nat =
          Zero : ( z) nat
        | Succ : ('n) nat -> ('n s) nat

  let rec of_int n : int -> 'n nat = function
        0 -> Zero
        | n -> Succ (of_int (n - 1))
end
```

Compiling yields:

```
Error: This expression [Succ (of_int (n - 1))] has type 'a s nat
   but an expression was expected of type z nat
```

The problem is that the return value of the function is set to z nat by Zero in the first pattern matching clause. Instead it should be something like 'a. 'a nat? This problem also occurs when trying to make a function that adds two different Nat:s.

Grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `int -> 'n nat`, means `forall n, int -> n nat`: the *user* of the function may choose at which `n`to use the function. So you could call the `of_int` function saying "hey, give me a `(z s) nat` this time", just like you can pick which type `[] : 'a list` ends up being. That doesn't match what really happens, which is that you do not choose the type, it is determined by the value of the integer.

By definition, the value of the integer is not known to the type system, so you can't say precisely which type `n nat` you will get as a result. All you can say is that there *exists* some type `n` such as the result has type `n` nat. You can express that using "existential types", and there are various ways to do that, GADTs being one of them (GADTs are algebraic datatypes plus existential types and equality constraints).

```
type some_nat =
| Some : 'n nat -> some_nat

let rec of_int = function
| 0 -> Some Zero
| n ->
  let (Some nat) = of_int (n - 1) in
  Some (Succ nat)
```

`some_nat` is an existential wrapping around `nat`, it is equivalent to what you might write `exists n. n nat` if you had first-class existential types.

Handling addition is even harder, because you have to express at the type level that the type you get in return really corresponds to the addition of two other types. Here is how I defined the type for it:

```
type (_, _, _) add =
| AddZ : (z, 'b, 'b) add
| AddS : ('a, 'b, 'c) add -> ('a s, 'b, 'c s) add

type ('a, 'b) add_result =
| Result : ('a, 'b, 'c) add * 'c nat -> ('a, 'b) add_result

let rec add : type a b . a nat -> b nat -> (a, b) add_result = function
   ...
```

I'll let you define the body of `add` so that you can play with this stuff yourself.

I'm not very happy of all the runtime wrapping that goes around the `add` type (which is really just useful as a type-level witness), so maybe there is a better way.

Comment: OK, I give up. :( The Haskell wiki made it look easy. Perhaps I should learn Haskell and/or ATS before trying this in OCaml. :P It's even possible in C++, goddammit! Thanks for your time, anyway.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt ATS will make *this* sound easy because it has an integrated theorem prover for arithmetic. Going outside the fragment that can be handled automatically (as you surely will if you're here trying to do in-code static proofs in OCaml) will land you in a related world of pain, with the difference than ATS was designed from the start to handle that (not OCaml), so for example they have a notion of "proof witness that aren't really computed at runtimes" (proof views). I think the simplest (not *simple*) way to do these kind of things is to use Coq or Agda directly, not Haskell.